# Similar expressions to "jump for joy"

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, synonyms, idiom-request

Is there an expression along the lines of "jumping up to the ceiling" which could be used to describe a situation when someone is so happy he's jumping very high?

Comment: The expression is "to jump for joy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Jumping up to the ceiling" is not an idiomatic expression, but there are a number of others related to being in an elevated position:

> jump for joy
>
> be on cloud nine
>
> be flying high
>
> be walking on air
>
> be over the moon
>
> be in heaven
>
> be on top of the world

and various others.  Also for general interest, there's ["dancing on the ceiling"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovo6zwv6DX4), which is not in common use, but still can be used.  It means to be having a good time at something like a party.  Be aware some people -- well, *older* people -- will invariably associate the phrase with the song and ask if you are a Lionel Richie fan.

In contrast, to "hit the ceiling/roof" means to react with *extreme anger*.

> Her parents **hit the ceiling** when they found out she borrowed the car without asking.